# Redux not rerendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I know there's a lot of posts on this, but I think I've got my reducer set up properly and state is returning updated state.

My initial state: 
`callHistory: null,`

My redux reducer:

```js
case CALL_HISTORY:
  return {
    ...state,
    callHistory: action.data,
    }
```

My component:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {

  const callHistory = useSelector(state => state.user.callHistory);
  console.log(callHistory); // logs the correctly updated state
  const ccId = getUserIdFromStorage(); // gets ccId using asyncStorage
  const [_, getDatabase] = useDatabase();

  useEffect(() => {
    renderDatabase();
  }, [])

  const renderDatabase = () => {
    ccId.then(id => getDatabase(id));
  }

if (callHistory) { // Invariant Violation: Dashboard(...): Nothing was returned from render.
  return (
    <Text>
      Loading
    </Text>
    )
  }
```

getDatabase:

```js
const getDatabase = ccId => {
    const docRef = db.collection("user").doc(ccId);
    docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        dispatch(callHistory(doc.data())); // correctly dispatches to store
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(error => console.log("Error getting document:", error));
  }
```

Any help or insights much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have an else condition for when `callHistory` is null. Your component must return something, even if its just returning `null`.

Add something like this:

```js
if (callHistory) {
  return (
    <Text>
      Loading
    </Text>
  )
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have used an else condition but it just stays in that condition forever because it doesn't re-render the component when `callhistory` is not null.

Comment: If your console log is logging the updated value like your code comment says, then that means it is being rerendered. I think you need to explain more about what's actually happening vs what you expect.